# Grundy value of Grundy's Game

Tags: math

I was working on a Grundy's game . The rules of this game is

For each pile , you have to split into unequal piles.

like for 6 it is {1,2,3},{2,4},{1,5} and not {3,3} .

The player who  makes the last move is the winner.

My problem is , how to find the Grundy values of this game. I know that G(1)=G(2)=0 as you

cannot split them but how is G(4)=0 , G(3) = 1 ?

Answer (score 0):

G(3) is 1 because you split it into 1,2 and the next player can't split either of those. G(4) is 0 because you are forced to split it into 1,3 at which point the other player splits the 3 pile and wins.

Comment: Can , you please do the same by using Minimum Excluded principle.

Comment: @user1139048: `G(3) = mex({G(1)+G(2)}) = mex({0+0}) = mex({0}) = 1`, and `G(4) = mex({G(1)+G(3)}) = mex({0+1}) = mex({1}) = 0`.